# Issue with Rust using dynamic polymorphism on trait when specifying lifetime on self

Tags: list, polymorphism, rust, self, traits

I have finally decided to give Rust (1.7 & 1.8) a try. Coming from C++, I must say Rust looks awesome. I was trying to reproduce a well known behavior in C++ that consists of using dynamic polymorphism on a set of objects.

I have been through a very annoying problem that I was able to solve, but I would like to know what you guys think of that issue, and I hope it might help others that are trying to do the same kind of thing.

Let's consider the following code that implements the initial idea:

```
struct Foo
{
    foo: u32,
}
trait Bar
{
    fn bar(& self) -> u32;
}
impl Bar for Foo
{
    fn bar(& self) -> u32 
    {
        return self.foo; 
    }
}
fn foobar(l: &std::collections::LinkedList<& Bar>)
{
    for i in l
    {
        println!("{}", i.bar());
    }
}
fn main()
{
    let foo0 = Foo{foo: 8u32};
    let foo1 = Foo{foo: 8u32};
    let mut l = std::collections::LinkedList::new();
    l . push_back(&foo0 as &Bar);
    l . push_back(&foo1 as &Bar);
    foobar(&l);
}
```

Here everything is compiling, everything is working perfectly.

I wanted to pass another reference to the function `bar` of the trait `Bar`, as a result I had to add a lifetime to the `Bar` trait. To keep it simple, I will just add the lifetime (as it will compile nicely under Rust 1.8). After adding the lifetime through the whole code, the code eventually looks like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    foo: u32,
}
trait Bar<'a>
{
    fn bar(& 'a self) -> u32;
}
impl<'a> Bar<'a> for Foo
{
    fn bar(& 'a self) -> u32 
    {
        return self.foo; 
    }
}
fn foobar<'a>(l: &std::collections::LinkedList<& 'a Bar>)
{
    for i in l
    {
        println!("{}", i.bar());
    }
}
fn main()
{
    let foo0 = Foo{foo: 8u32};
    let foo1 = Foo{foo: 8u32};
    let mut l = std::collections::LinkedList::new();
    l . push_back(&foo0 as &Bar);
    l . push_back(&foo1 as &Bar);
    foobar(&l);
}
```

If you compile this code, the error message will be the following:

```
../test.rs:21:12: 21:13 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
../test.rs:21   for i in l
                         ^
../test.rs:19:1: 25:2 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn foobar<'a>(l: &std::collections::LinkedList<&'a Bar>)
../test.rs:19 fn foobar<'a>(l: &std::collections::LinkedList<& 'a Bar>)
../test.rs:20 {
../test.rs:21   for i in l
../test.rs:22   {
../test.rs:23     println!("{}", i.bar());
../test.rs:24   }
              ...
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Here the problem is clear, the compiler knows that the variables given in `push_back` have different lifetimes, hence it cannot be compliant and disagree with what I have written. The problem can be solved if the variables `foo0` and `foo1` are declared in the same `let` statement.

I found it very hard to figure out what was wrong in that code.
My questions are:

- Is there a way to tell the compiler that a collection might take different lifetime?
- By setting the `'a` lifetime on the other reference variable (that does not appear here) instead of `self`, the code compiles. Does that mean if we do not specify any lifetime then the compiler puts the `'_` that correspond to the specific lifetime I am asking in my previous question?
- Is there an implicit rule that "forbids" us to set a lifetime on self?
- Is that piece of code idiomatic Rust?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for this kind of question...

Comment: Please ask [only one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829). The answer to "is it idiomatic" may be found on Code Review, but please review [this post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/32521) before moving your question there. Perhaps you can pick one of the functional questions and reword your question to focus on it to start with?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: No, it doesn't appear to be because 1.) errors are mentioned and 2.) all the `Foo`s and `Bar`s indicate that this is mostly hypothetical code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second code sample will compile if you change the definition of `foobar` to this:

```
fn foobar<'a>(l: &std::collections::LinkedList<&'a Bar<'a>>) {
    for i in l {
        println!("{}", i.bar());
    }
}
```

However, what you're doing with lifetime parameters doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

We usually define a trait that is generic over a lifetime (such as your second version of `Bar`) when we want to have a method that returns a reference whose lifetime is the lifetime of a member of the implementor. For example, suppose we have the following struct:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    foo: &'a str,
}
```

This struct contains a reference, and we must explicitly name that lifetime. We want to allow any lifetime, so we define a lifetime parameter, `'a`.

We can add an inherent method to this struct:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'a str {
        self.foo
    }
}
```

Notice how `&self` doesn't have an explicit lifetime. Instead, we use the `'a` parameter from the `impl` on the return type of the `foo` method, since we want the lifetime of the returned value to be the same as the lifetime in the struct, not the lifetime of `self` (which would usually be shorter).

What if we wanted to define a trait method similarly?

```
trait Bar<'a> {
    fn bar(&self) -> &'a str;
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&self) -> &'a str {
        self.foo
    }
}
```

The trait `Bar` defines a lifetime parameter and the `impl` links it to the lifetime parameter of `Foo`.

Instead of adding lifetime parameters on the trait, you can also add lifetime parameters on individual methods too.

For example, consider this trait:

```
trait Slice {
    fn slice<'a>(&self, s: &'a str) -> &'a str;
}
```

We want the result to have the same lifetime as the `s` parameter. To do this, we need to define a lifetime parameter on the method and apply it on both references.

For completeness, here's an implementation of that trait:

```
struct SliceBounds {
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}

impl Slice for SliceBounds {
    fn slice<'a>(&self, s: &'a str) -> &'a str {
        &s[self.start..self.end]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Francis, I realized that there is absolutely no point putting a lifetime on self itself as it is not related to it in any way. I guess I was confused by the fact that we set the lifetime on the trait on the "impl" line.